# SQL Server and Hibernate - datetime2 vs varbinary

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, grails-orm, hibernate-5.x

Hibernate saves the older Java Date objects as a datetime2(7) in SQL Server, and Hibernate saves the newer Java LocalDateTime objects as varbinary(255) in SQL Server. Are there any issues with performance, for instance searching greater than/equal to or less than/equal to datetimes using varbinary(255) vs datetime2(7)? I'm using Hibernate 5 through GORM in Grails 3.2 to connect to an Azure SQL Server.